# Is it possible to post to google+ account using web application?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Is this possible to Implement the ability to post to Google+ platform using web application?
I have searched through https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started but did not find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

follow the link
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp.
VS c# sample is also available

Comment: Thanks for the response Eugene, i will try this link.